# Google Calendar API Freebusy: query does not retun events separatly

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api, google-api-nodejs-client, google-calendar-recurring-events

In my google calendar I have events back to back:

- event1 9 a.m - 11 a.m
- event2 11 a.m - 13 p.m
- event3 13 p.m - 15 p.m

When I query Freebusy api it retruns one event: **9 a.m - 15 a.m** rather than separate events, Why ?

Client post request:

```
$.post(
  "url",
  function (result) {
    var events = [];
    result.map((event, i) => {
      item = {};
      item["title"] = "SameTextToDisplay";
      item["start"] = event.start;
      item["end"] = event.end;
      events.push(item);
    });
  }
);
```

My nodejs server function:

```
calendar.freebusy.query({
  resource: {
    timeMin: TimeMin,
    timeMax: TimeMax,
   timeZone: "America/New_York",
    items: [
      {
        id: "MyCalendarID"
      }
    ]
  }}, (err, resp) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
  res.send(resp.data.calendars[id]);
   });
```

Comment: Could you maybe share what is the actualy response (JSON object)  you are recieving? If you are calling the free/busy endpoint wouldn't this be expected? In the end you are getting that information, you are not trying to retrieve the events of the calendar.

Comment: here is the JSON retunred: {start: "2020-04-21T09:00:00-04:00", end: "2020-04-21T15:00:00-04:00" }

Comment: How can I separate this chunk of date into 3 separate dates ? Can you recommend some javascript code ?

Comment: Well, you'r right @Raserhin after all freebusy function does what it was designed for, I use the event.list to have the list of event rather.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a list of events, use the endpoint [`event.list`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) rather.

There is an example on how to use the `list` endpoint with the javascript library in [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js).